# Global trivialization of a Principal G bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be a variety and $E$ be a principal $G$ bundles, where $G$ is a semisimple group. Is there a variety $f: \tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ such that $f^*E$ is trivial $G$ bundle?

Comment: Are you interested in an online study group or a group blogging?? I am reading some differential geometry, category theory, algebriac geometry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a principal $G$-bundle is trivial if and only if it has a section, and if you take $\tilde{X} = E$, then $f^*E = E \times_X E$ has a section given by the diagonal map $E \to E \times_X E$.

Comment: Another way to see that $f^*E$ is trivial is that its classifying map $E \to BG$ factors through $EG$ which is contractible.